# php немного геометрии

Tags: php, массивы, get

Помогите найти причину ошибки
Код:

```
$halfperimeter = [];
$sourceA = [];
$sourceB = [];
$sourceC = [];
// В этом цикле вычисляем полупериметр и каждую сторону

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    $triangle = new Triangle();
    $halfperimeter [] = $triangle -> Perimeter()/2;
    $sourceA [] = $triangle -> getA();
    $sourceB [] = $triangle -> getB();
    $sourceC [] = $triangle -> getC();
}

//Вычисляем площадь по формуле Герона

$geron1 = ($halfperimeter);
$geron2 = ($halfperimeter-$sourceA);
$geron3 = ($halfperimeter-$sourceB);
$geron4 = ($halfperimeter-$sourceC);
$geron5 = ($geron1*$geron2*$geron3*$geron4);
$geron6 = sqrt ($geron5);

echo $geron6;
```

Ошибка

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Unsupported operand types in W:\domains\localhost\alextestphp\task1\triangleTest.php:93 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in W:\domains\localhost\alextestphp\task1\triangleTest.php on line 93

Линия 93 - $geron2

Делая

```
//print_r ($sourceA);
//print_r ($sourceB);
//print_r ($sourceC);
//print_r ($halfperimeter);
```

Все значения корректно возвращает.

Не могу понять что ему на нравится.

Comment: Если что формула //Формула Герона S=sqrt{p*(p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c)} *S-площадь p-полупериметр abc-стороны

Comment: Подсказка: `$halfperimeter` - это массив. собственно как и все `$source...`

Comment: у меня в каждом массиве по 10 значений, как можно их заставить между собой отниматься-множиться что бы структура массивов не изменилась?

Comment: А как ты заносил значения? так же и производить манипуляции по сложению, очевидно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже сказано выше - Вы из массива вычитаете массив.
Следующий код пройдет по всем значениям массива и выведет $geron6 для каждого из 10 элементов

```html
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
  $geron1 = ($halfperimeter[$i]);
  $geron2 = ($halfperimeter[$i]-$sourceA[$i]);
  $geron3 = ($halfperimeter[$i]-$sourceB[$i]);
  $geron4 = ($halfperimeter[$i]-$sourceC[$i]);
  $geron5 = ($geron1*$geron2*$geron3*$geron4);
  $geron6 = sqrt ($geron5);
  
  echo $geron6 . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, думал надо доставать из массива, юзать и потом обратно засунуть, а оно вот как. 
Еще раз всем спасибо!